# input[disabled=true] and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How can you make `input[disabled=true]` work in jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/Bps9U/

Comment: @Justin - his jsfiddle doesn't work; although he hasn't explained it very well, what he wants is for both input fields in the result box to be yellow. There are several answers now which explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`disabled` is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), and as such has only two states: Set and not set.

The following are all equal:

```
<input disabled="true">
<input disabled="disabled" />
<input disabled>
<input disabled="">
```

You can match all variants with `$("input[disabled]")`.

With jQuery, you can get the state of an element with `$(...).prop('disabled')`, which will return a boolean.

Comment: `.attr` and `.prop` have been cleaned up somewhere around jQuery 1.6, please update your answer (http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: @Kos Updated. By the way, stackoverflow is [maintained collaboratively](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), so feel free to edit answers yourself.

Answer (score 2):

1) `.attr` instead of `.prop`. [The docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
2) Use `disabled` string as attribute value (instead of `true`)

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bps9U/4/)

*Edit* As *Kos* points out in the comments, [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is a valid function in jQuery 1.6 or later.

Comment: The docs you're linking to say: *"To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements*, **use the .prop() method"**.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, but this remains high in google searches and SO is a wiki :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is your original code:

```
$('<input class="inp" type="text" value="jquery" />').prop('disabled', true).appendTo('body');
```

There are two bugs in this code:

Firstly, the JQuery function you should be using is `.attr()`, not `.prop()`.

Secondly, the `true` needs to be set as a string, because as you have it now, it's just setting it to the Javascript boolean value, which is not the same as the `"true"` that you want to use.

However, I would also point out that the correct value for the `disabled` attribute is actually `disabled="disabled"`, not `disabled"true"`. Both will work in all browsers, but the former is the correct value, so that's what you should use.

Given all that, we can update your code to look like this:

```
$('<input class="inp" type="text" value="jquery" />').attr('disabled', 'disabled').appendTo('body');
```

...and change your HTML and CSS to use `disabled="disabled"` and `input.inp[disabled=disabled]`.

(by the way, the CSS could also be written as just `input.inp[disabled]`, which would work for any value of the attribute)

Hope that helps.